# Using a 3rd party control

Tags: vb.net, calendar, controls

Please excuse the noobness that is probably about to follow...

I'm making an vb.net 2010 app which needs to have a calendar system in which the user can add appointments and events etc.

I've downloaded the source for a control which looks promising (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar) but I have no idea how to add this in to my project. I've googled for help on adding the control but have had no luck.

If I right click on my toolbox, go 'choose items...' and try and add it there, it tells me it couldnt be opened.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've downloaded the source code.

Place the source code in a specific location on your pc and then compile it 9If your planning to use this control in your own project then compile it in release mode.  Assuming that there are no compile errors close visual studio and then open up the project of your own that you want to use this control in.

Right click on the general tab in the toolbox and click choose items.  Using the bowse button in the choose items dialog navigate to the folder in which you placed the source code for the control you want to use.

Now locate the 'Bin' folder and in that locate the 'release' folder.  Inside that you will see a dll (named presumably something like MothCalendar.dll.  Select that dll and then click add and OK  (Button sequence will vary according to vs version).  The control should then appear in your toolbox under the general tab and you should then be able to drag it onto your forms for use in your project.